# Как добавить динамический метод из одного класса в другой Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, классы, методы

В классе кнопки нужно выполнить метод из другого класса. Два варианта:

1. Сделать другой класс статичным, но это не даёт сделать **gameObject.name** в свиче.

   ```
   public void Start()
   {
    Statistic.inGameStatistic();
    switch (gameObject.name)
    {
        //case "lvlTxt":
        //    value = SeePerson.monsterId;
        //    break;

        case "mHealthTxt":
            value = SeePerson.monsterHealth;
            break;

        //case "mArmorTxt":
        //    value = SeePerson.monsterArmor;
        //    break;

        case "mStrengthTxt":
            value = SeePerson.monsterStrength;
            break;
    }

    text.text = value.ToString();
   }
   ```
2. Оставить этот метод динамическим, тут снова два варианта развития событый:

2.1 `MonsterStatistic.Start();` код не запускается, ошибка: **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MonsterStatistic.Start()'**

2.2`MonsterStatistic mnS = new MonsterStatistic();` `mnS.Start();`, здесь код запускается, unity выдаёт предупреждение: **You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.**, и код выполняется неправильно

Comment: найти инстанс класса, а потом у него вызвать метод. Или же создать инстанс класса и у него вызвать метод.

Answer (score 1):

На тему ваших вариантов... нет! Их не два и уж явно не те, что вы написали.

У `Button` есть событие `OnClick` где можно указать ссылку на любой компонент и его публичный метод с аргументом или без.

Компоненты (`MonoBehaviour`) привязаны к `GameObject` и никак не могут быть статическими по своей природе. Но класс может тупо содержать статическую ссылку на один экземпляр.

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static Foo Main { get; private set; }

    public void Awake () 
    {
        Main = this;
    }

    public void DoSomething () { }
}
```

---

```
if (Foo.Main != null)
    Foo.Main.DoSomething();
```

Вариантов много, вопрос только в том чё вы хотите сделать... Насколько можно понять, у вас есть некий класс отвечающий за статистику, но не понятно почему он `MonoBehaviour`... Вам скорее нужен `Singleton`.

```
public class Statistics
{
    private static Statistics _instance;

    public static Statistics Instance
    {
        get {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new Statistics();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Statistics ()
    {
        Load();
    }

    public void DoSomething () { }

    private void Load () { }

    private void Save () { }
}
```

---

```
Statistics.Instance.DoSomething();
```

Comment: MonoBehaviour потому что первый раз в юнити и большую часть познаю опытным путём) Статистка конкретно в этом вопросе не причём, просто нужно было обратиться к этому классу

Comment: Если **этот** класс тоже компонент, то на него просто можно оставить ссылку в инспекторе, объявив соответствующее поле. А вообще лучше не заниматься фигней ставя безталковые опыты с путём в никуда, а для начала какойнибудь курс пройти на ютубах, коим нет числа и имя им легион. Практика идёт за познанием материала, а не на оборот.